# Spyder5 crashes with error paramiko version

Tags: spyder, paramiko

After installing new spyder version I get this error during startup. The version in the environment seems ok though. Anyone had a similar issue?

[image: spyder startup]

[image: conda list]

Comment: Maybe you could try to update `paramiko` and check if that helps Spyder pick it. I think the latest available version on the anaconda default channel is `2.7.2`: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/paramiko/files

Comment: Yeah I had 2.7.2 initially with the error,  then downgraded it to 2.6.0

Comment: That's quite strange. What version of Spyder are you using?

Comment: Their latest 5.1.5